# alter ajax callback

Tags: 7, ajax

Is there a way to alter an ajax callback from a form? I need to add a custom command after the existing one.

Or to alter the existing command defined in the js file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is [`hook_ajax_render_alter(&$commands)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/7)